# Update selectedIndex options menu with JQuery.MSDropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using a `<select>` options menu with [jQuery.msDropDown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) but for some reason the DOM won't update after setting the `select.selectedIndex` property with javascript/jquery.

After I click on the drop-down menu then click back on the page (to close it) it does update with the correct selectedIndex.

I'm updating the selectedIndex in a loop like this:

```
    $.fn.[unrelated function].after = function( opts, curr, next, fwd ) {
        var $sel = document.getElementById('selectElem');
        for(var i = 0, j = $sel.options.length; i < j; ++i) {
            if(($sel.options[i].value).substr(1) == next.title) {
                //I have tried various ways here
                $sel.selectedIndex = i;
                //$('#selectElem').prop("selectedIndex",i);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

P.S. there doesn't seem to be any documentation for `msDropDown` otherwise I would have tried to identify what event would trigger an update of the box.

Comment: jQuery hint: $('#selectElem') is a shortcut for document.getElementById('selectElem');

Comment: @Diodeus in the chance that jQuery may have had extra functionality to fix these things I also tried the jQuery method

Comment: @Ozzy Why the down vote?  You didn't mention in your code that you tried `$('#selectElem').attr('selectedIndex',i);`.  Sorry, I'm just trying to help.

Comment: You can't assume Ozzy was the one who down-voted.

Comment: @Diodeus Aha, so it was you!

Comment: No, I just don't like assumptions.

Comment: @Ross I down-voted your answer because if you read my question carefully I specifically wrote 'I have tried various ways here' and gave an example because I knew I'd get a tonne of junk answers like yours (don't take it to heart)

Comment: @Ozzy I undeleted my original answer and edited it.  I hope this solves it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this -

```
var oHandler = $('#selectElem').msDropDown().data("dd");
if(oHandler) {
    oHandler.set("selectedIndex", i);
}
```

Comment: Great - it works, really appreciate that. Changed my vote to an up-vote too.

Comment: @Ozzy Awesomeness, just trying to help, no worries about the confusion :~)

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the complete code:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Country").msDropdown();


    var country_code = 'in';
    var i = 0;
    var indexNumber = 0;
    $("#Country option").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == country_code){
            indexNumber = i;
        }
        i++;
    });
    var oHandler = $('#Country').msDropDown().data("dd");
    if(oHandler) {
        oHandler.set("selectedIndex", indexNumber);
    }

});
```